# How to add smbutil as a lookup mechanism for hostnames

Tags: macos, command-line, smb

There are a bunch of computers on my network that are not on the DNS server. They broadcast their name using Samba or are Windows Workgroup machines.

When I run either ping or try to access them over the browser, it does not work.

However I am able to do a `smbutil lookup thathost` and get their ip address.

What should I do to get Mountain Lion to add smbutil as a mechanism to resolve hostnames when other mechanisms, i.e. `DNS`, `Bonjour`, `/etc/hosts` fail?

Answer (score 1):

I like the mdns service discovery tool: `dns-sd`

So to check for SMB shares:

```
dns-sd -B _smb._tcp
```

You can then parse the instance names to get other details to look up like IP address and then check other services on that host with a tool like `nmap`